# How to verify HTML template in Angular apps?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm writing karma/jasmine unit test for an Angular app.  The idea is to verify, that the HTML template is valid.

Suppose a simple component "my-comp".  And suppose, I would use the following HTML template, which calls a non-existing property:

```html
<my-comp [noop]="dummy"></my-comp>
```

During execution of the app, I would get a template parse error:

```
Can't bind to 'noop' since it isn't a known property of 'my-comp'.
```

Now, I would like to check this during tests.  However, the unit test passes, and the component get initialised.

Is there a way to detect this kind of error in tests?

Comment: When you say the component gets initialized, did you execute fixture.detectChanges()?  I ask because that would attempt to actually create the component in the DOM and at that point should give you the same error in the test.

Comment: Yes, detectChanges is called.  Besides, there is some logging output from the component.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal for an Angular component and test.

In your case `[noop]=dummy` will not work if you don't provide an `@Input()noop` on the component.  No such property exists and hence compilation will fail.

However, during the test, the when you do

```
line1  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
line2  const component = fixture.componentInstance;
```

This will generate a component based on your definition in your component.ts Hence,  you dont see any failure.

If you have linter set on your VS project, you will notice that if you add:
`component.noop` after  line2,  there will be a error in your test file as this property doesn't exist on your component.

Comment: Well, there is no use to add `component.noop` in the test.  It is obvious, that this would fail.  The thing is, that I want the test to verify, that all the templates in the app are correct and do not use any non-existing properties.  This is necessary, because developers may mistype names, or during refactoring not all places are found and fixed.  Anyways, building the app with `-aot` also reports all these errors.

Comment: In this case, the build /ng serve will fail, just like in cases when you use a bootsrap component telling the dev that there is no such associated property ( if they are passing non-existant property). 
To pass all required property, you should usually have a default value for your showstopper @Input and an APi to explain what they do. Usually these are inside a  component. Config.ts.You can have a look at some specs on https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/popover/popover-config.spec.ts